# Return Parameterized Query Results with MVC and EF

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to use Visual Studio 2013, MVC and Entity Framework to return results of a stored proc to display data to a user.  I've already added the EDMX model to my solution and completed the Function Import Wizard for the stored procedure I am looking to execute.  What I am stuck on is how to code the Model and Controller and return the data to the View. I don't want to use the generated CRUD operations and scaffolded views EF creates.

**Stored Proc**:

```
SELECT C.ClassName, G.Grade
FROM Classes as C
INNER JOIN Grade as G on C.ClassID = G.ClassID
WHERE C.UserID = @UserID
```

**Model**:

```
public class TestModel
{
    public string ClassName {get; set;}
    public string Grade{get;set;}
}
```

**Controller**:

```
public class TestController : Controller{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
       TestEntities db = new TestEntities();
       var result = db.TestEntities ("@username");
       ViewBag.Results = result.ToList();
       return View(result.ToList());
    }
}
```

**View**:

```
<table>
  <h>ViewBag.Results.ClassName</h>
  <h>ViewBag.Results.Grade</h>
</table>
```

This is just the simple code.  My references are all in tact.

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck? "how to code the Model and Controller and return the data to the View" is way too broad.

Comment: @GertArnold I'm having trouble when I run the code after following Octavioccl direction.  I am getting the following error "An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The underlying provider failed on Open."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already map the stored procedure in your EDMX, you must have a method like this on your context:

```
 [DbFunction("TestEntities", "YourStoreProcedureName")]
 public virtual IQueryable<TestModel> YourStoreProcedureName(int UserID)
 {
        var userIDParameter = UserID != 0?
            new ObjectParameter("UserID", UserId) :
            new ObjectParameter("UserID", typeof(int));

        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.CreateQuery<TestModel>("[TestEntities].[YourStoreProcedureName](@UserId)", userIDParameter);
 }
```

So, you can call it from your context this way:

```
TestEntities db = new TestEntities();
var result = db.YourStoreProcedureName(1).ToList();
```

Check this [page](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2014/04/01/calling-stored-procedures-from-entity-framework.aspx) to see more details about this.

Now, if you want to call a parametrized query using EF, you can do it as I show below:

```
 var query =String.Format( @"SELECT C.ClassName, G.Grade
                            FROM Classes as C
                            INNER JOIN Grade as G on C.ClassID = G.ClassID
                            WHERE C.UserID = {0}",UserId);
TestEntities db = new TestEntities();
var result = db.Database.SqlQuery<TestModel>(query).ToList();
```

And, if you want to call a stored procedure that is not mapped in your EDMX, you can call it this way:

```
  TestEntities db = new TestEntities();
  var result = db.Database.SqlQuery<TestModel>("YourStoreProcedureName", new SqlParameter("UserId",1)).ToList();
```

Comment: -   I created the method in my "ProjectName.Context.cs" file under the ProjectNameModel.edmx.  Was that the correct place? My next question is, should I call the sp from the context on the Model or Controller? Thanks.

Comment: Well, the edmx lets you map SPs that already exist in your DB, check this tutorial:http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/30738a7c-5176-4333-aa83-98eab8548da5.aspx.  Regardless of when you add your stored procedure, the Designer will add code like the first method that I show in my answer to the DbContext object it writes for you. So that is the right place. About the 2nd question, I would call the SP from the Controller.